# WPF LOB Application - Client Specific Control Changes

Tags: wpf, configuration, styles

I have written a WPF Line of Business application that has a particular sections which need to have a slightly different user interface (swapping out some checkboxes for a combobox) for a particular customer.

I want to avoid having to maintain multiple copies of this window. Is there a way that I can make use of a resource(s) (style, template, etc) so that the content for this particular section can refer to a client specific resource file?

I hope that this question makes sense.

EDIT: Is there an answer somewhere in using control templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two `UserControl`s that represent the two sections and swap them programatically or through binding.